# Should I add my contribution to OEIS in my CV?

Tags: mathematics, cv

I am working on the enumeration of some relations in Combinatorics, which is a branch of Mathematics.

OEIS is an online digital repository of over 3,50,000 integer sequences, and it has been cited in more than 800 papers.

I have a contribution to OEIS. It is sequence [A345317](https://oeis.org/A345317).

Should I add my contribution to OEIS in my CV?

Comment: It depends on where and for what kind of position you apply. Without knowing anything about this: One such sequence (out of the huge number in the repository) doesn't look that impressive to me.

Comment: @Roland I would think the context behind a contributed entry would matter more than the number of entries one has contributed. Considering the size of the OEIS, hardly anyone can be expected to have lion's share of the contributions to the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I add my contribution to OEIS in my CV?

Yes, but do try to say more about it than just, "I contributed A345317 to the OEIS." Surely some research has gone into its discovery, so describe that in brief. Because, that will determine how interesting and relevant your addition to the OEIS appears in the eyes of whoever reads your CV.

The impact of your contribution might also depend on your level. A contribution by a high-school student would be intriguing, so I would strongly recommend putting it on your CV. If you're an under-grad or grad student, it would still be worth putting on your CV, but I would expect to see the surrounding research highlighted more than the bare bones of your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, there are two ways to go about it - either it is important on its own to warrant a publication, or goes into some "uncategorized" heap sometimes present in the CV. After all, you showcase what *you* think is important and representative of your work as a whole. Now, if you include it in the "main" section, let's see it through the eyes of someone reading it, *assuming there's no article it's acting as a supplementary for* (I couldn't find one):

- If it is obscure, you just submitted a sequence into that online repository and it has little traction - that is not a particularly strong result AND you chose to showcase it. Probably that's indicative of how your work as a whole is...
- If it is some well-known result - but still not published as an article - perhaps the result is good but you seemingly failed to recognize that. Not great again.

Therefore, to me it only makes sense to include as a part of "other" work like reports, research grant participation, case studies or what you might have there.